# Not getting the length of nodes in the linked list program

Tags: linked-list

After I got some break from work, I have continued to learn about linked lists. I am using Dev C++ and having some trouble with the code. Here is the code and I referred this code from here [link](http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/103/LinkedListBasics.pdf)!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node                      //Definition of a Node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

struct node* build3nodes()        //Create nodes and allocate memory
{
    struct node* first = NULL;
    struct node* second = NULL;
    struct node* third  = NULL;

    first = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    second = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    third = malloc(sizeof(struct node));


    first->data = 1;
    first->next = second;

    second->data = 2;
    second->next = third;

    third->data = 3;
    third->next = NULL;

    return first;
}

unsigned char length(struct node* head)    //Get the number of nodes 
{
    unsigned char count = 0;
    struct node* current = head;
    if(current!=NULL)
    {
    count ++;
    current = current->next;
    }
    return count;
}

int main()
{
    unsigned char len = 0;
    struct node* head1 = NULL;
    head1 = build3nodes();
    len = length(head1); 
    printf("Length is %d",len);


}
```

When, I compile and run this program, I get the output length as 1 while I have to get 3, since there are 3 nodes present. In the debug mode, I stepped through each line while checking the variables added to watch, and I noticed that, even though the variable **current** in the function **length()** is not equal to NULL, yet it exits the while loop while incrementing the **count** by just 1. So, basically, the **count** variable should increment till 3 until it reaches the 3rd node having its next field pointing to NULL. But this is not happening and I don't understand what I am doing wrong. Any advise and help regarding this would be great. Thank you all in advance!

Kind Regards
~VD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an easy fix, what you have right now inside the length is a condition rather than a loop. So it will only go through it once if the condition is true. What you want to do instead is that change that into a while loop condition which will enable you to traverse the whole linked list until you see NULL.

So change

`if current != NULL` to `while (current != NULL)`

Comment: Ohh Yeah rite!. How did I miss that one. Thanks for pointing it out. Its working now :)